# Разный порядок данных hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Когда достаю Set пользователей из бд используя гибернейт, они всегда приходят в разном порядке, с чем это связано и можно ли как-то контролировать не используя сортировку после получения?

Comment: `Set` хранит данные неотсортированными. Так что вам или после получения их надо отсортировать или в БД запрос делать так, что бы ответ был или отсортирован или не `Set`

Comment: а какой метод считается более удачным?

Comment: по идее бд оптимизирует запросы на сортировку или не критично?

Comment: Какой метод лучше - не знаю. Если у вас данных относительно немного (~1000), то, думаю, разницы не будет особой. Но я бы попробовал заставить БД возвращать отсортированные данные, ибо, думаю, так оно производительнее чуть-чуть будет.

Comment: Используйте List. В запросе ORDER BY по соответствующему полю. Кроме того в ORM могут делают это самостоятельно, при включении специальных опций. Например в JPA есть аннотация @OrderBy(), применяемая к спискам

Comment: Ещё можно результат запроса переложить в SortedSet

Comment: В моём случае вариант использования List'a не очень годится, т.е. мне стоит присмотреться к SortedSet и в него записывать данные, которые дёргаю из гибернейта.